# What does default CSS's browsers depend on?

Tags: html, css, browser, user-agent

Hi (please excuse me for my ugly english ;-) )

Do you know if the default CSS of any user agent ... :

- depends on its release number ?
- depends on its layout engine ?
- depends on the release number of its layout engine ?
- depends on the OS ?
- depends on the OS release number ?

If yes (for any choice), have you any example do demonstrate it ?

Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: To be fair, the French version was probably to help clarify the English version in case of translation issues.

Comment: You can also see Firefox's default CSS as a normal stylesheet by entering `resource://gre/res/html.css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only depends on the browser make/version. You can find [here](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm) an overview of default styles.

The main differences are in the margins of the block elements. One would recommend to use a [CSS reset](http://google.com/search?q=css+reset) sheet to clean it up, but I'd just specify the margin for every actually-to-be-used block element yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the rendering engine used by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically need to know the defaults properties for your project - I'd recommend looking into using a 'reset script'.

If you use such a script, it will standardise the CSS defaults so they're the same across a range of browsers.  Yahoo produce a good one, which is updated with each browser release (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)